# how to crop a zoomed image using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, image, zooming, crop

I have to make a `customized avatar` in which i need to `zoom image and crop that` using jquery
i found many plugins for zooming and cropping separately but precisely none for both . the server side i use is `PHP.`

Answer (score 1):

I use [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) to crop it. It allows you to set a marquee at a certain aspect ratio and see a live preview in another div (the preview is zoomed in if you're working with an image big enough to support the zooming).

It has several examples and also a script for PHP cropping on the back end and it also handles converting the hi-res cropped image to the correct size thumbnail.

Answer (score -1):

Use

> imagemagick crop

http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick

Comment: can u explain how it is used??